# How to assign CSS to mobile page in asp.net

Tags: css

I am developing the asp.net mobile application. I am generating the controls dynamically at serverside (code behind), obviously i will need to assign the styles to control on server side. So that I have my own CSS ie external CSS. I want to assign the classes from my CSS to mobile controls. How can i do this?

i am using asp.net mobile application development environment with code behind c#. please help. This is new for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way on my question. see the code..:
 
 `<.mobile:DeviceSpecific ID="DeviceSpecific1" Runat="server">
                <.Choice Filter="supportsJavaScript" Xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com /mobile/html32template">
                    <.ContentTemplate>
                        <.html>
                         <.link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                        <./html>
<./ContentTemplate>`

```
            <./Choice>
        <./mobile:DeviceSpecific>
```

<./code>

and I had access this style sheet and applied.
NOTE: Please remove the dots when using this code from tags.<. >